# Scale object in place keeping its origin

Tags: python

New to blender, working on some plugin for 2.8.

I need to scale an object, but keep it in place. These objects come from a file and I cannot mess with their origin nor position.

My original thinking was to set the object origin to geometry center, apply the scale, then restore the origin. But I haven't found a reliably way to do this.

Is there a way to scale an object in place without changing its origin?

Comment: You can scale the objects in Edit Mode.

Comment: Scaling an object relative to it's origin should never move said origin. Your question is unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Matrix equivalent of global scale bounding box center.**

*Note both of these examples use the bounding box center as pivot point.*

Could as suggested scale the mesh, akin to edit mode scale.  If scaling the mesh  use local coordinates. Note this alters the mesh coordinates, but keeps the origin and object global translation same.

To scale about a non origin point, first translate such that pivot point is origin, then scale, then move back.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector

context = bpy.context

scale = (2, 2, 1)

ob = context.object

bbox = [Vector(b) for b in ob.bound_box]
o = sum(bbox, Vector()) / 8


T = Matrix.Translation(o)
S = Matrix.Diagonal(scale).to_4x4()
T2 = Matrix.Translation(-o)

M = T @ S @ T2

ob.data.transform(M)
ob.data.update()
```

**And a global version.**

Make a scale matrix and two translation matrices, one to make scale origin bounding box global center, the other to move it back.

Note this will not alter the mesh or its origin, but will translate the object to match the scale, to give object appearance of scaling in place.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector

context = bpy.context

scale = (2, 2, 1)

ob = context.object
mw = ob.matrix_world
bbox = [Vector(b) for b in ob.bound_box]
go = mw @ sum(bbox, Vector()) / 8



T = Matrix.Translation(go)
S = Matrix.Diagonal(scale).to_4x4()
T2 = Matrix.Translation(-go)

M = T @ S @ T2

ob.matrix_world = M @ ob.matrix_world
```